# Q learning, what are the states, action and reward for game of rummy?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am working on q learning algorithm for rummy, I have to generate a Q table where it goes as Q[state, action], since in game of rummy, actions are either pick or drop i have the value set to 2 where as when it comes to states, what are the number? (Question 1)

For now the cards in the deck/pile/stash are A, 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7 of each type, thats about 28 cards + 4 Aces does that mean i have 32 states? if so what does it actually mean when i update the Q table value in it. (Question 2)

In the above mentioned case, how do i design a reward table (Question 3)

Help appreciated.